# The generated report in DOCX format has invalid margins

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using *JasperReports* to generate a word (docx) document but I have a problem when I want to try to print the doc. The exporter messes up the margins of the page. Does anyone know how to prevent that from happening.

I know how to set the margin in *iReport*, but it just makes the data generate further from the page borders, but the margins in word which can be adjusted at the top of the page is laying right at the edge.

Has anyone had this problem?

Answer (score -2):

Are you able to specify the page size?  Its possible that using this in combination with the margin settings will help the export problem.

If you are not too heavily invested in your Jasper solution, [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) and [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) let you layout the document visually using Word or Writer then render the report in various formats.  This may save you time in the long run, but all reporting systems have quirks.  Hope you find a solution, especially when your output is not PDF.